# Finding a point on the right side of a line at a given distance

Tags: c, math, vector, geometry

I want to find the point at distance `d` on the right side of a line defined by `P1(x1,y1)` and `P2(x2,y2)` (the distance is calculated from the middle of the line). I came up with the following code, which works well, but I think I have made unnecessary calculations, and it can be done faster.

```
#define PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592308

double x2, x1, y1, y2, px, py, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, d, ax, ay, b, dx, dy;

d = 2.0; // given distance
ax = (x1 + x2) / 2; // middle point
ay = (y1 + y2) / 2; // middle point
b = tan(atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) + PI / 2); // slope of the perpendicular line
dx = (d / sqrt(1 + (b * b)));
dy = b * dx;
p1x = ax + dx;
p1y = ay + dy;
p2x = ax - dx;
p2y = ay - dy;

// cross product
if (((x2 - x1) * (p1y - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (p1x - x1)) > 0)
{
    px = p1x;
    py = p1y;
}
else
{
    px = p2x;
    py = p2y;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `atan`, `b` value, cross product to check orientation (moreover, `b` might be zero and cause division error).

Instead calculate normalized (unit length) direction vector and get right normal to it:

```
d = 2.0; // given distance
ax = (x1 + x2) / 2; // middle point
ay = (y1 + y2) / 2; // middle point
dx = x2 - x1;
dy = y2 - y1;
scale = d / sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);   //distance/vector length
px = ax + dy * scale;  // add normal vector to the right side of p1-p2 direction
py = ay - dx * scale;   //note minus sign
```

Answer (score 1):

For *generating* a 2D vector perpendicular to another, one result that falls out from a special case of the dot product is that you can swap the two components of the vector and negate one of them.

For example, let's say you have the vector `d` which points from `p1` to `p2`:

```
dx = p2x - p1x;
dy = p2y - p1y;
```

And now you want to generate `right` which is perpendicular, it is simply:

```
rightx = dy;
righty = -dx;
```

Now, let's do a quick visual check for our definition of "on the right", in case we actually want to negate those two values...

```
  o p2 = [2, 3]
 /
o p1 = [0, 0]
```

Above, `d` is simple: `[2, 3]`.  Intuitively, we would think of (as viewed from above) walking from `p1` to `p2` and looking to the right, which would mean a vector in the positive X direction and the negative Y direction.  So yes, that looks fine.

Note: If your co-ordinate system is screen-based (*i.e.* positive Y direction is down), then the inverse is true (and you would negate both the terms in the calculation of the `right` vector).  This is due to the *handedness* of the co-ordinate system being left instead of right.

Now, you can calculate the midpoint `mid` as either `(p1 + p2) / 2` or `p1 + d / 2`.

```
midx = (p1x + p2x) / 2;
midy = (p1y + p2y) / 2;
```

And finally to generate `p3` you start from `mid` and extend down the vector `right` by an amount `height`, you need to normalize that vector by dividing by its length and scale by `height`.  Formally, the final point will be `mid + right * height / length(right)`.

This is the only particularly expensive part of the calculation, because it needs a square root.

```
rdist = height / sqrt(rightx * rightx + righty * righty);
p3x = midx + rightx * rdist;
p3y = midy + righty * rdist;
```

Congratulations!  You now have an isosceles triangle!

Comment: It should be noted that there is a degenerate case which in this code will result in a divide by zero -- that is when `p1` and `p1` are equal (or very near precision limits).  Intuitively, you can consider there are either infinite solutions (a circle around the point), or no solutions (there is no line perpendicular to a point).  Either way, you may want to handle that _somewhere_ if it's relevant.